# Why is one op-amp in my circuit messing up the other?

Tags: operational-amplifier, troubleshooting

I am attempting to create a board that takes an input signal, outputs the buffered input signal and its inverse, and then also outputs the difference of those signals once affected by an outside impedance. I attached an image of the schematic below:

[image]

When I only have the "FOLINV" dual op amp installed in the circuit, the "INVOUT" and "FOLOUT" signal are exactly what I want.

However, when I insert the "DIFF" op amp into its socket as well, *the inverse signal out remains good, but the follower signal becomes 1/2 its original amplitude and is inverted.*

1. Would this be expected from my circuit design, or does it indicate that something is wrong with my assembly?
2. How can I fix this issue?

Thank you for your time,
Josh

Comment: Please post an image that is legible and rotated anticlockwise through 90 degrees.

Comment: You need to show details of the power supply and bypass capacitors.

Comment: I can't read the labels, but the three resistors on the left-hand side form a 3-way voltage divider where the output of the op-amp controls the bottom voltage of the divider and therefore affects FOLOUT.

Comment: @user253751 Thank you, that makes sense to me! What would you suggest as a solution? Would it be effective to add additional op-amps in-between to buffer?

Comment: @Andyaka Thank you, I didn't realize how poor the quality was - It should be better now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitively, R1 and R5 both pass the same current, and by Ohm's law that means R1 drops over \$\frac{2}{3}\$ of the signal. The same goes for R2 and  R6, and this is why the signals appearing at INVOUT and FOLOUT are so severely attenuated.

The gain of stage DIFFA is controlled by the ***combined*** impedances R1+R5 and R2+R6. You can't just thrown in R1 and R2 without reducing the gain of the differential stage significantly, for the reason above.

In this case, without R1 and R2, the gain of the differential stage would be \$\frac{4.7k}{4.7k}=1\$, but with R1 and R2 in place, gain drops to \$\frac{4.7k}{4.7k+10k} = 0.32\$

If you require outputs FOLOUT and INVOUT to have source impedance (which I presume is the intended purpose of R1 and R2) without having this drop in gain, try this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmeJho.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The differential stage inputs are now provided with signals from zero-impedance sources, instead of zero+10kΩ sources, and it will have a gain of 1.

Outputs FOLOUT and INVOUT will have potentials SIGIN and −SIGIN respectively, as long as you don't draw significant current via their artificial source impedances R1 and R2.

Answer (score 0):

When you insert the 3rd op-amp (diff) the first series resistors (R1, R2) become part of the 3rd op-amp's active circuit.  Remove the first set of series resistors. If you really want the extra 10K of isolation then add those resistors in series with the output connector lines (the circuit branch going to FOLOUT and INVOUT).

Comment: Thank you for your response. It is important that R1 and R2 remain in the circuit as they form part of an active bridge. Would it work instead to place voltage following op amps before R5 and R6 to buffer the signal?

Comment: That would be yet another option, (extra buffer op-amps).